# Oracle SQL Loader - How to not display "Commit point reached - logical record count" counts

Tags: sql, oracle, loader, sql-loader

I'm loading big files via Oracle SQL Loader over vpn from home, and they're taking a lot of time. They were a lot faster to load when I loaded them from work. The files I'm loading are on my work server already.

So my thinking is that the slow down is because of the "Commit point reached - logical record count" that is printed for each row. Must be slow due to them having to be sent over the network. I googled but can't find any way to print less of them. Tried adding rows=5000 as a parameter, but I still get the prints for each row.

How can I print less of the "Commit point reached - logical record count" counts?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the keyword `silent`, which is available in the [options clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_control_file.htm#i1009196). You can set the [following things](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_params.htm#SUTIL004) to be silent:

> - HEADER - Suppresses the SQL*Loader header messages that normally    appear on the screen. Header messages still appear in the log file.
> - FEEDBACK - Suppresses the "commit point reached" feedback messages    that normally appear on the screen.
> - ERRORS - Suppresses the data error messages in the log file that    occur when a record generates an Oracle error that causes it to be
>   written to the bad file. A count of rejected records still appears.
> - DISCARDS - Suppresses the messages in the log file for each record    written to the discard file.
> - PARTITIONS - Disables writing the per-partition statistics to the log    file during a direct load of a partitioned table.
> - ALL - Implements all of the suppression values: HEADER, FEEDBACK,    ERRORS, DISCARDS, and PARTITIONS.

You would want to suppress `feedback`.

You can either use on the command line, for instance:

```
sqlldr schema/pw@db silent=(feedback, header)
```

**Or** in the options clause of the control file, for instance:

```
options (bindsize=100000, silent=(feedback, errors) )
```

Comment: Thanks, no more display. Sadly it's still taking the same time to load the data :-(

Comment: If you don't have any indexes in your table and you don't mind doing a direct path load try using the `direct=true` option, which should help as would increasing the commit interval (far more than using stdout). Up the commit interval to 20k and it will go quicker.

Comment: so far so good(+1) thanks, but I think the statement should be without parentheses such as `sqlldr schema/pw@db silent=feedback, header`.

Answer (score 0):

Try redirecting output and error to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Ben's answer is very good.  Do not use any shell program to suppress the `STDOUT`.  I used the following:

```
sqlldr schema/pw@db mycontrolfile.ctl | sed '/Commit point reached/d'
```

One of the problems with this is that if you are using scripts to run the command, then the error return value will be flushed by the sed command.  Put it another way, if for some reason, the sqlldr failed with return value of 1, then sed will immediately flush this with return value of 0.  So your error state will be flushed.

Redirecting `STDOUT` and `STDERR` might not be as good as Ben's solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem while calling `sqlldr` from a shell script.

**ERROR:**

> SQL*Loader: Release 10.2.0.3.0 - Production on Tue Aug 9 20:06:38 2016
>   Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> Commit point reached - logical record count 64
>
> SQL Loader failed for the table myschema.ORG_MOVEMENT_RULES. Exiting...

Upon Investigation, found that the control file `(v_movementrules_control)` got corrupted while copying from a Windows to Unix system and it got DOS/Windows line ending characters `^M` at end of every line.

```
sqlldr userid=${USER}/${PASS}@${DB} control=${v_OrgRules_Control}
```